# How can one import affect the other in matplotlib and pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-import

I'm having difficulties understanding this import feature and I would like some help with it.

Running this code

```
import matplotlib as mpl
fig = mpl.figure.Figure()
```

returns the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'figure

However, if besides importing matplotlib I also import matplotlib.pyplot. Such as,

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = mpl.figure.Figure()
```

Then, `mpl` does include `figure` and no error is raised.

In fact, running `print(dir(mpl))` gives different results whether pyplot is imported or not.

Why does one import affects the other?

What is the intention in having it behave this way?

Comment: It is good to understand exactly what pyplot is.  https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html

Comment: https://twitter.com/TedPetrou/status/1238812789935869953